# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow - if any value equals value

Tags: 2013, workflow

if any value equals value condition not allow to put value 
and also if I take it from lookup not allowed integer value

[image: first case]

[image: second case]

Comment: Hi @Ahamed Mustafa, can you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: thx Amal I already edit my question

Comment: ID field should be compared with an integer value. So if you place any other values (string etc) then it will not work.

Comment: even I put the Id not allowed also

Comment: I tried similar and I was able to put an integer value. Can you close designer and try again.

Comment: try to close it more than once and not allowed

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you get when clicking OK

Comment: no messages when I put the exact value is show "value" again 
and about lookup when I click OK not show any messages

Comment: I have this exact same behavior working with SharePoint Online.

Comment: I had to use a local workflow variable to workaround this issue, since it would happily accept that for some reason.